# Multidimensional arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have searched and tried but can not come up with anything.

The following code creates an array "ary_task_group".  I need the second array "ary_task" to be under the key of ary_task_group.  This shouldn't be a hard thing to do but in javascript, it seems to be a bit difficult.

```
$('.task-group-text').each(function(key, value) {
    var taskGroup = $(this);
    var taskGroupName = taskGroup.html();
    var grouped = taskGroupName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
    ary_task_group[key]=taskGroupName;

    //get the children for this group.
    $(".group-container-"+grouped).find(".task-expand").each(function(task_key, task_value){ ary_task[task_key] = $(this).html()  });
    console.log(ary_task);
});
```

**EDIT**

Trying to create an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.group = [];
obj.group = taskGroupName;
obj.group_tasks = [];
$(".group-container-"+grouped).find(".task-expand").each(
    function(task_key, task_value){ 
    //ary_task[task_key] = $(this).html()
    obj.group_tasks.push[{task_key: $(this).html()}]  
});
```

This results in only the last item in the object.  I know I am doing this part wrong.

Comment: Create an object for that.

Comment: An array doesn't have "keys", it's all index based `[1,2,3]` - an object has keys `{ name : "ted" }`.

Comment: why you are using this one                                     obj.group = taskGroupName;

Comment: if you look final solution below, I took it out.  Not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, creating an object was the way to go obviously.  Here is my code I ended up with.

```
$('.task-group-text').each(function(key, value) {
    var taskGroup = $(this);
    var taskGroupName = taskGroup.html();
    var grouped = taskGroupName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
    ary_task_group[key]=taskGroupName;

    //get the children for this group.
    var ary_task = [];
    $(".group-container-"+grouped).find(".task-expand").each(
        function(task_key, task_value){ 
            ary_task.push($(this).html())  
        }
    );
    obj[taskGroupName] = {
        ary_task
    };

});
```

Which results in:

```
Array
    (
        [Group 2] => Array
            (
                [ary_task] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Test task group 2
                    )

            )

        [Group 777] => Array
            (
                [ary_task] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Funny Face
                        [1] => Test Task group 1
                    )

            )

    )
```